# Permissions issues in Docker image while gradle is trying to write to an out directory

Tags: docker, gradle, dockerfile

I am building a docker image which will contain gradle, and other tools used for testing the application.

So, I have created a new Dockerfile based on a corporate docker image with one of the tools I need, then strapped gradle after that, courtesy of 
[keeganwitt](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/baa15d43de55bec37dcd5648ed1ef07f3e27f9aa/jdk8/Dockerfile).

My run command looks like this:

```
docker run -it  --mount source=~/app-repo/appName,target=/home/gradle/,type=bind app_unittests:gradle_sahi /bin/bash -c "whoami;pwd;chown --recursive gradle:gradle /home/gradle; gradle test --tests test.automation.tools.TestSahi --debug --stacktrace"
```

So this works, it starts running, and eventually I get:

> Failed to create parent directory '/home/gradle/out' when creating directory '/home/gradle/out/classes/java/main

Also note that I added the chown command to my docker run command (lifted from the gradle dockerfile) - but it also runs into permission issues on everything...

I also checked `docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID>`:

```
  "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/root/app-repo/appName",
                "Destination": "/home/gradle",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "66dcb821f5687c55821ec908ea7ad041065477fa9328cd5cd47e21cf7d7a0028",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/66dcb821f5687c55821ec908ea7ad041065477fa9328cd5cd47e21cf7d7a0028/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/gradle/.gradle",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

As well as Mounts under HostConfig:

```
 "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "bind",
                    "Source": "/root/app-repo/appName",
                    "Target": "/home/gradle/"
                }
            ]
```

You can see, it IS mounted `RW:true`.

Please help..

Comment: what do you get when you run `id -u` and `id -G`?

Comment: @Keegan do you mean the container or the host? Its 0 and 0 in host machine (root user) and 1000 and 1000 in container (as gradle user).
I should note that the problem is gone by changing the host mounted directory to 777 recursively. However then when gradle runs sahi (a testing tool installed in /sahi_pro) its unable to access it due to perms. Ideally I want gradle to work as ROOT, to eliminate permissions issues.

Comment: I meant inside the container and compare that to the ids the directory permissions have on the host.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `ls -n /root/app-repo/appName` (on the source).  If the ids are not `1000`, you will need to chown the directory (`sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /root/app-repo/appName`) or run the container as root (`docker run --user root` or `user: root` in your Docker compose file).